# Rails why is my params not being passed to my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My params in my view is only passing sometimes. The link should look like `localhost:300/user_stocks?ticker=TSLA&user=1`  but all I see is `localhost:300/user_stocks?user=1`

view code

```
<% if @stock %>
  <div class="card card-header results-block">
    <strong>Symbol: </strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
    <strong>Name: </strong> <%= @stock.name %>
    <strong>Price: </strong> <%= @stock.last_price %>
    <%= link_to 'Add To Portfolio', user_stocks_path(ticker: @stock.ticker, user: current_user), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success", method: :post %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller code where I am sending the params

```
stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:ticker])
stock = Stock.new(ticker: params[:ticker], name: stock.name, last_price: stock.last_price )
```

stock is coming back as nil because some reason the params[:ticker] is not passing

Comment: What are you trying to do here? it is not clear whether are you trying to save new record/trying to view the record

Comment: maybe you need `method: :get` instead of `method: :post`.

Comment: Does your ticker model implement a to_param method? If yes, worth checking what it has in there, if no then try adding one and seeing if that makes any difference. to_param is the method that is called internally when representing one of your models in url params https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Comment: @NatarajaB I am trying to save a new record by having the user click add to portfolio button but some reason my params is not even passing most of the time. Sometimes it does which I don't see why its not doing it all the time